# How to prove the limit identity theorem

Tags: limits, proof-writing, definition

I have to prove what I know as the Identity Theorem of Limits, although I have not found many places using this term, but I don't know where to begin with

The theorem states that the $\ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)\ $ exists and is equal to $\ L\ $ if, and only if, both $\ \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x)\ $ and $\ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)\ $ are equal to $\ L\ $.

The book I use usually says that a proof to a theorem using "if and only if" has two parts, one for the "if" and the other for the "only if". My idea is to do it by using the definition of limits, but it doesn't work as far as I've tried:

I started with what I know:

$\lim_{x \to a^{-}} f(x)$: for all $\ \epsilon_1>0\ $ there's a $\ \delta_0>0\ $ such that $\ 0<a-x<\delta_0\ $, then $\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_0\ $

$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$: for all $\ \epsilon_1>0\ $ there's a $\ \delta_1>0\ $ such that $\ 0<x-a<\delta_1\ $, then $\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_1\ $

$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$: for all $\ \epsilon>0\ $ there's a $\ \delta>0\ $ such that $\ 0<|x-a|<\delta\ $, then $\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon\ $

Then, I would try to compare any of the lateral limits with the bilateral one, but I came to the conclusion it makes no sense, since I'll never be able to compare $\ a-x\ $ to $\ x-a\ $ because they're the inverse to the other, and because these values should be considered as always getting smaller and smaller and not simply small valued constants. Now, no other idea has come to my mind.

Anyone has a hint on how to do this?

Comment: This is an exercise in unwinding definitions. You must do it yourself to grow as a mathematician.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, I get that, but I do need a hint on where to begin. I am having trouble on writing it mathematically and not descriptively

Comment: Can you show us your attempt for the proof? If you're really just stuck at the beginning then a good first step is typically just to start by writing out the definitions of whichever side you're starting with

Comment: @StephenDonovan, there you have it, I edited to show my first steps.

Comment: You say you'll never be able to compare $a-x$ and $x-a,$ but can you try to rewrite the inequality in the first definition in terms of $x - a$? (also, I would recommend giving the different deltas and epsilons indices, it helps to keep them straight)

Comment: If I got this correct, it's done

Comment: There MUST be a mistake on the definition of $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ since $0>x-a<\delta_0$ (weird notation btw) means that $x-a<0<\delta_0$ (since we already have $\delta_0>0$) so the only restriction in $x-a<0$ and $\delta_0$ does absolutely nothing. Instead, it should read $0<a-x<\delta_0$.

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre, well, yes and no, for x approching a from the left, x is always smaller than a, so $x-a<0$, I inverted because I thought that's what Stephen Donova ment, but it seems it's not that

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin, note that $x-a<0\iff 0<a-x$ so what I said implies $x<a$. The definition on this question is wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit has the definition and diagrams that illustrate it.

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre, yes, I get it, but as I said, I thought I got Stephen Donovan's hint correct, but I didn't that's why I edited the original question from what you just said that is correct to the current one

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin The change you had made is in the spirit of what I was getting at, the execution was just a bit off. I would suggest multiplying through by $-1.$ (and don't forget to flip the signs)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
For $c>0$,
$$\begin{align}0<|a-b|<c & \iff a\neq b \land |a-b|<c\\ &\iff a\neq b \land -c<a-b<c\\ & \iff a-b\in (-c,c)\setminus\{0\}\\
&\iff a-b\in (-c,0)\cup(0,c)\\
& \iff a-b\in (-c,0)\lor a-b\in (0,c)\\
& \iff -c<a-b<0\;\lor \; 0<a-b<c\\
& \iff 0<b-a<c\;\lor \; 0<a-b<c\end{align}$$

Try using $$0<|a-b|<c\iff 0<b-a<c\;\lor \; 0<a-b<c$$

to conclude.